# play 2.5 render view test, access to flash messages

Tags: testing, junit, playframework, playframework-2.5

Here the simple play render view test. In view template i trying to accesss session information throught flash.get().
But test failed with message `There is no HTTP Context available from here.` How add fake session data to tested application in junit  test context?

```
public class ApplicationTest  extends WithServer {

private FormFactory formFactory() {
    return app.injector().instanceOf(FormFactory.class);
}

@Test
public void renderTemplate() {
    Content html;
    session().put("session","123");
    html = index.render(formFactory().form(Auth.Login.class));
    assertTrue(contentAsString(html).contains("Hello"));
}
```

}

```
Test ApplicationTest.renderTemplate failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here., took 0.544 sec
 at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:57)
 at play.mvc.Http$Context$Implicit.flash(Http.java:307)
 at views.html.index_Scope0$index$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(index.template.scala:39)
 at views.html.index_Scope0$index$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(index.template.scala:38)
 at views.html.helper.form_Scope0$form.apply(form.template.scala:35)
 at views.html.index_Scope0$index.apply(index.template.scala:38)
 at views.html.index_Scope0$index.render(index.template.scala:141)
 at views.html.index.render(index.template.scala)
 at ApplicationTest.renderTemplate(ApplicationTest.java:37)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `WithServer` starts up an application that you can make requests to.  For the tests you describe here, you need to use `WithApplication`.

To manually set a context, you can override the `startPlay` method.

```
@Override
public void startPlay()
{
    super.startPlay();
    Http.Context.current.set(new Http.Context(1L,
                                              Mockito.mock(RequestHeader.class),
                                              Mockito.mock(Http.Request.class),
                                              Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(),
                                              Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(),
                                              Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap()));
}
```